# R create a datatable by row

Tags: r, database, datatable, row, rbind

I want to have a dictionary datatable, to make different versions of a country's name correspond to one unique value.

It would therefore be something like :

```
Value_found          Output
UK                   United Kingdom
United Kingdom       United Kingdom
United-Kingdom       United Kingdom
```

And so on. Now this table will be created by line and not by columns each time I encounter a new version.
I know how to append a new row with `rbind` but this works when just adding one new observation.

I wonder if there is a way to create the initial datatable by row, instead of the traditional column way of doing it `DF <- data.table(Value_found=c("UK", "United Kingdom"),Output=c("United Kingdom", "United Kingdom"))` that I see everywhere but do not see very practical in my case (but in a lot of case in fact)
`

Comment: You could just write a comma-separated file and then `fread` it in directly to a `data.table`

Answer (score 1):

`tibble::tribble()` has this functionality:

```
tibble::tribble(
  ~Value_found,      ~Output,
  "UK",              "United Kingdom",
  "United Kingdom",  "United Kingdom",
  "United-Kingdom",  "United Kingdom"
)

# A tibble: 3 x 2
  Value_found    Output        
  <chr>          <chr>         
1 UK             United Kingdom
2 United Kingdom United Kingdom
3 United-Kingdom United Kingdom
```

It outputs a "tibble", which is a slightly modified version of a `data.frame`.  https://tibble.tidyverse.org/